# Spring Data Solr ConverterNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, solr, spring-data, spring-data-solr

I'm trying to configure Solr (with Multicore Support) in my application and I get a `ConverterNotFoundException` whenever I try and register converters.

I've stepped through and can see the query being executed and documents being returned. Just the converters not being found.

I followed the example from the official docs [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/solr/docs/current/reference/html/#solr.mapping.mappingSolr).

Hopefully someone can shed some light on what's going on as examples are hard to find and the docs aren't overly clear about adding converters when using `multicoreSupport=true`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableSolrRepositories(
        multicoreSupport = true,
        basePackages = {"uk.co.foo.bar.repository"})
public class SolrConfig {

    @Resource
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public SolrClient solrClient(HttpClient httpClient) {
        String solrHost = environment.getRequiredProperty("solr.host");
        return new HttpSolrClient(solrHost, httpClient);
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpClient httpClient() {
        ModifiableSolrParams params = new ModifiableSolrParams();
        params.set(HttpClientUtil.PROP_BASIC_AUTH_USER, "user");
        params.set(HttpClientUtil.PROP_BASIC_AUTH_PASS, "pass");
        return HttpClientUtil.createClient(params);
    }

    @Bean
    public SolrConverter solrConverter(CustomConversions customConversions){
        MappingSolrConverter mappingSolrConverter= new MappingSolrConverter(new SimpleSolrMappingContext());
        mappingSolrConverter.setCustomConversions(customConversions);
        return mappingSolrConverter;
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomConversions customConversions(){
        return new CustomConversions(Arrays.asList(new fooConverter(), new barConverter()));
    }

    @Bean
    public SolrTemplate solrTemplate(SolrClient solrClient, SolrConverter solrConverter){
        SolrTemplate solrTemplate = new SolrTemplate(solrClient);
        solrTemplate.setSolrConverter(solrConverter);
        return solrTemplate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having multicore support enabled currently does not allow to register global `CustomConverters`. Unfortunately there's no workaround available. I'll take care of [DATASOLR-173](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATASOLR-173) to get this fixed.

Comment: Thanks, was going out of my mind trying to figure out what was happening!